# ARTEFACT download from nexus failing because the data is cached

Tags: maven, nexus

I am using curl to publish to maven:

```
 const curlOptions = [
                '--silent',
                '--output', '/dev/stderr',
                '--write-out', '"%{http_code}"',
                '--upload-file', fileLocation,
                '--noproxy', options.noproxy ? options.noproxy : '127.0.0.1',
                '--fail'
            ];

 const curlCmd = ['curl', curlOptions.join(' '), targetUri].join(' ');

 const childProcess = exec(curlCmd, execOptions, function (error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(chalk.red(error));
                }
            });
```

This works for the upload but the artefact gets cached and I cannot get the artefact from curl without going to nexus and running rebuild metadata on the affected artifact.

Can i programmatically invalidate the cache?

Comment: What version of NXRM is this for?

Comment: @joedragons nexus 3

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, it should be possible to invalidate cache in later versions of NXRM3 using the REST API and the "/beta/repositories/{repositoryName}/invalidate-cache" endpoint.
It should also be possible to do the same and run the scheduled task (rebuild metadata; /v1/tasks/{id}/run endpoint) though that seems a less desirable route as that is generally used for repair.

You can see more on the REST API in the [NXRM3 documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/REST+and+Integration+API) though the intent of some is that it's self documenting by using the Swagger UI in the application.  Note at time of this answer, only those with the nx-admin privilege can access the Swagger UI (though people with proper permission can use the endpoints).  You can find the Swagger UI in the Admin section under System -> API.

That being said, I think there's likely something else going on.  I don't think it should be necessary to invalidate your cache like that each time.  I didn't want to go too far from the question however.  I encourage you to look at community.sonatype.com for answers to what else might be going on and ask there if you don't see one.

Comment: i can’t seem to find any online reference to this `invalidate-cache`  call

Comment: @dagda1 Yeah, you'll have to look in app.  It's part of the "self documenting" they are attempting.